# Change model field value after button click

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I do really know that is a common topic but I've already checked every solution i could find and it did not work for me. 
I would like to add user points using button click.

views.py

```
 def add_points(request):
        if request.GET.get('mybtn'):
            profil = get_object_or_404(Profile, created_by=request.user)
            profil.points += 10
            profil.save(update_fields=["points"])
            return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to="profile_pics")
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    people = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

html file

```
<div>
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="+10 pkt" name="mybtn"/>
                </form>
</div>
```

I have tried diffrent solutons but nothing really worked out for me.

Comment: If you want to display the change in point, use javascript instead. To modify it in database, create a separate django view function that takes in ajax requests sent from client. The ajax request would also be in javascript.

Comment: I don't really need it to update live on screen. I just want to update it in the database and display it later after refreshing a page.

Comment: Use `ajax`. The logic you had will force a reload of webpage - which is *bad*. with `ajax` you can separate your logic into 1. put it into a database in another function, 2. use another separate javascript function to update the webpage itself entirely on client side. If you insist though, your method should be able to work - but you're not passing the `profil` back to the render object, hence it never gets updated.

Comment: What is the actual issue or error you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/) function.

```
from django.db.models import F
      def add_points(request):
                if request.GET.get('mybtn'):
                    profil = get_object_or_404(Profile, created_by=request.user)
                    profil.points = F('points') + 10
                    profil.save(update_fields=["points"])
                    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!